# Lógica para verificar mês com Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando verificar os meses que possuem 31 dias com `.test()` mas quando o valor referente ao mês é `10` (referente a *novembro*, que possui 30 dias - lembrando que no JavaScript os meses são indexados em zero, então *novembro* é o mês 10) o retorno é `true`. Percebi que isso se dá por conta do `0` de `10` que está casando com o `0` em `[024679]` na Regex que estou usando abaixo:

```js
var mes = "10";
var teste = /[024679]|11/.test(mes);
console.log(teste);
```

Qual seria a forma mais simples de fazer com que o `10` retorne `false` na Regex acima?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta usar os [delimitadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, para marcar o início e fim da string. Assim ele não pega o zero do `10` sem querer:

```js
var mes = "10";
var teste = /^([024679]|11)$/.test(mes);
console.log(teste);
```

Também coloquei em parênteses para garantir que entre o início e fim só tem uma das duas opções (os números 0, 2, 4, 6, 7 e 9, ou o 11). Apenas para esclarecer a diferença:

- `^[024679]|11$` (sem parênteses): significa que a string começa com `[024679]` **ou** termina com 11
- `$([024679]|11)$` (com parênteses): significa que a string começa, depois temos `[024679]` **ou** 11, e depois temos o final da string.

A diferença é sutil, pois sem parênteses a regex vai aceitar `"2000"` (pois começa com 2) ou `"111"` (pois termina em 11). Por exemplo:

```js
console.log(/^[024679]|11$/.test("2000")); // true
console.log(/^[024679]|11$/.test("111")); // true
console.log(/^([024679]|11)$/.test("2000")); // false
console.log(/^([024679]|11)$/.test("111")); // false
```

Além disso, usar o `$` também garante que a regex não pegará o `"2000"`:

```js
console.log(/^([024679]|11)$/.test("2000")); // false
console.log(/^([024679]|11)/.test("2000")); // true
```

---

A solução acima, é claro, assume que a string só vai ter os dígitos do mês, e nada mais. Se ela tiver outras informações, basta mudar os delimitadores (uma opção é usar `\b`, por exemplo):

```js
var teste = /\b([024679]|11)\b/.test("abc 11 xyz");
console.log(teste); // true
teste = /\b([024679]|11)\b/.test("abc 10 xyz");
console.log(teste); // false
```

Mas aí já depende de como o mês estará nas suas strings.

Comment: Legal. Testei apenas com o `^` no início e atendeu bem, porque não vai pegar o `0` do `10`. Mas os meses são apenas esses mesmos: 0, 2, 4... e 11, ou seja, até outubro é apenas 1 dígito, novembro e dezembro que são 2: 10 e 11. Valeu!

Comment: @Sam Atualizei a resposta, vi que tinha alguns casos que falhava e coloquei mais alguns exemplos (inclusive, explicando porque acho que usar `$` é melhor) :-) É claro que se suas entradas são validadas e a regex sempre recebe um valor do mês válido, não precisa de tanto preciosismo. Mas de qq forma, fica o registro :-)

Comment: Tá só o oro! Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Caso precise filtrar o mês de uma data formatada como "DD/MM/AAAA", pode usar:

```js
var teste = /(?=.*\b\/(\d{2})\b)/.test("06/05/1980");
console.log(teste); // true
```